# CallBase = true In Moq

Tags: c#, moq

Hi team I am new to moq and not able to understand concept of

```
CallBase = true;
var mock = new Mock<IFoo> { CallBase = true };
```

According to git hub :Invoke base class implementation if no expectation overrides the member

But I have below test case in which i am able to mock base class member without using CallBase = true

```
// Creating Base class.
public abstract class Car
{  
   public virtual bool IsValidSpeed()
    {
        ///complex logic
        ///returnig false just to compile code
        return false;
    }
}

// Creating child class
public class Ferrari : Car
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
     public void PrintSpeed(int speed)
    {
        if (IsValidSpeed())
        {
            Speed = speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Below writing test case.
  I am not setting property CallBase = true for my mock object

```
 public void MoqPracticeTest2()
 {
    //  var mock = new Mock<Ferrari>() { CallBase = true }; 
    var mock = new Mock<Ferrari>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    //Mocking Base class function
    mock.Setup(x=>x.IsValidSpeed()).Returns(true); 
    //calling function which will call base function
    mock.Object.PrintSpeed(100);
    //calling Verify on mock object
    mock.Verify(x => x.IsValidSpeed(), Times.Once);
    Assert.AreEqual(mock.Object.Speed,100); //Doing Assert
 }
```

still above test case is passing without setting callback property.
 can some one please explain use of `CallBase = true` here.

Comment: @chirstos I have used var mock = new Mock<Ferrari>() { CallBase = true }; //var mock = new Mock<Ferrari>(MockBehavior.Strict); Now also my test case is passing.I am using latest moq dll

Comment: I suppose that you have this statement also `mock.Setup(x=>x.IsValidSpeed()).Returns(true);`. If so this is quite reasonbale because the base implementation would be called only when you have not provided a setup like the above.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to set the `CallBase` to `true`, since you just want to verify that *provided that* `IsValidSpeed()` returns `true`, the speed of the `Ferrari` object would be the one provided to the `PrintSpeed` method.

So by declaring the following:

```
mock.Setup(x=>x.IsValidSpeed()).Returns(true);
```

you can simulate this specific scenario, without getting into the details on how `IsValidSpeed` is implemented.

On the other hand, just try this. Remove the above line and set the `CallBase` to true. This time you should note that the assertion would fail. This is due to the fact that the actual method would be called and the value of `false` would be returned, as you have already mentioned in your post. Hence in this case the value of provided speed would not be assigned to `Speed`.